# If Shinzon were to replace Picard how is the age difference explained?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng

I was doing some figuring about Shinzon's age in [Star Trek: Nemesis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_Trek:_Nemesis). The more figuring I did the more confused I became.

Am I right in the understanding that Shinzon was designed to replace Picard in Star Fleet, in the sense that no-one would know what happened, but the person who people thought was Picard is actually Shinzon? Given the physical appearance of Picard and Shinzon in the film there is clearly an age difference. How would this work if Shinzon were to replace Picard? Obviously people would notice he looked 20 years younger.

I assumed the answer to this has to do with some accelerated aging serum, similar to the one used in Star Wars with the clone army. However, after reading [this Memory Alpha article](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Star_Trek_Nemesis) I couldn't find any mention of such.

Another thing I'm trying to figure out is when did the Romulan Empire come up with this idea? Picard must have already been high-ranking in Star Fleet. But does that make sense? For example, if Shinzon was 25 when he faced Picard then the Romulans must have planned to replace Picard 25 years ago. Was Picard that high priority a target 25 years ago?

Comment: If the Romulans had been really clever they would have just made up some sort of [transporter accident](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Rascals_%28episode%29) story.

Comment: Or they could have got a mining ship to go backwards in time through a black hole.  Oh, wait...

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Beverly states with confidence that Shinzon is 25 years old. Since the film takes place in 2379, this means that Picard's clone would have been created when he was still in command of the USS Stargazer in 2354, some ten years *before* he gained command of the Enterprise.

In-universe there are two possible explanations for this discrepancy;

- Picard may have already been marked for greatness. His command of the Stargazer was exemplary and he was known as a military genius who'd invented his own [unbeatable maneuver](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Picard_Maneuver).
- Tasha Yar, thrown back in time in TNG : [Yesterday's Enterprise](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Yesterday's_Enterprise_(episode)) could have told the Romulans that Picard would one day be in command of the flagship of the Federation.

> **BEVERLY :** *There's no doubt, Captain.  Right
>             down to your regressive strain of
>             Shalaft's Syndrome.  He's a clone.*
>
> A beat as the confirmation sinks in.
>
> **PICARD :** *When was he... created?*
>
> **BEVERLY :** *About twenty-five years ago.  They probably used a hair
>   follicle or skin cell.*

As to how they planned to replace Picard despite the age difference, Beverly works it out:

> **BEVERLY :** *The more I studied his DNA the more confusing it got.  Finally I could only come to one conclusion... Shinzon was created
>   with temporal RNA sequencing.  **He was designed so that at a certain
>   point his aging process could be accelerated to reach your age more
>   quickly, so he could replace you.***
>
> **PICARD** : *But the Romulans abandoned the plan...*
>
> **BEVERLY** : *As a result the temporal sequencing was never activated.  Remember, **he was supposed to replace you at nearly your
>   current age.  He was engineered to skip thirty years of life.**  But
>   since the RNA sequencing was never activated, his cellular structure
>   has started to break down.  He's dying.*

---

Elsewhere in the Star Trek canon, according to "[Death in Winter](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Death_in_Winter)", the harvesting of Picard's DNA supposedly took place in 2348 at the wedding of Jack and Beverly Crusher. To add insult to injury, Picard wasn't the only Starfleet officer that was cloned :

> But then, who would suspect him of being a surgically altered Romulan
>   spy—an agent dispatched across the deceptively quiet Neutral Zone in
>   support of a program only the praetor, in his brilliance, could have
>   conceived?
>
> **A plan to grow clones from the genetic material of Starfleet’s most
>   prominent captains and, at some opportune juncture years or even
>   decades hence, replace them with their secret progeny. Brilliant was
>   probably an under-statement.**
>
> It wasn’t difficult for the Romulan to make off with his prize.
>   Picard’s gaze had already drifted in the bride’s direction again. And
>   in the process, Manathas had been forgotten. Making certain no one was
>   watching, he emptied what was left of Picard’s champagne into another
>   glass—one that had earlier been the property of the bride—careful not
>   to disturb the smudge where the captain’s mouth had come in contact
>   with the transparent rim.

Comment: Also there was a photo of a younger Picard that Senior Picard was looking at during the movie, which looks like Shinzon http://i.stack.imgur.com/dpjwg.jpg

Comment: @Jared - Well, you'd expect that, given that they're clones :-)

Comment: @Jared - we don't bring up that picture. The lack of hair directly contradicts the younger Picard's appearance in "Tapestry", which took place AFTER the picture was supposedly taken.

Comment: @Omegacron - Or not. I'm guessing that they still have wigs in the future.

Comment: @Richard - Blasphemy! Picard wiggeth not!

Comment: @Omegacron - [WIIIIIG](http://www.billpetro.com/wp-content/uploads/sejanus-734380.jpg)!

Comment: @Richard - you, sir, are now dead to me.

Comment: @Omegacron He also had some hair through most of TNG.  Most likely he for some reason simply shaved his head for a period when he was younger.

Comment: "Brilliant was probably an under-statement." Is it though?

Comment: @Harabeck - The long-term planning required, the need for high-level espionage to get clean samples, the genetic manipulation and brainwashing of subjects? I'd describe that as nothing short of ambitious in the extreme

Comment: @Valorum Ambitious? Absolutely! But I'm not sure going through that amount of effort and risk is particularly brilliant. That's a lot of moving parts. K.I.S.S. and all that...

Answer (score 2):

Question 1. Shinzon was cloned with temporal RNA that would allow him to be aged quickly to Picard's current age once activated. Also, one of the first things Memory Alpha says about Shinzon. The Romulans also dropped this project and sent Shinzon to Remus as basically a slave.

Question 2. Picard gets the Enterprise in 2364, and Nemesis takes place in 2379 (also making Picard 65 in this movie) So we have a few options with this one,

1. They hatched this plan right when Picard got the Enterprise, or shortly thereafter, then grew and rapidly aged Shinzon partially to an age where they could teach him etc, before finishing the age change to Picard's current age.
2. This is a plot fail and they didn't work out the math before they made the movie; Shinzon should only be about 15.
3. Picard had been in Starfleet for years before his assignment to the Enterprise, and so they could have picked him as a promising young member of Starfleet in about 2333-35. Picard was promoted to captain of the U.S.S. Stargazer after the previous captain died in combat. During his years as a captain of the Stargazer, it makes more sense for the Romulans to decide to clone him.